# Proof of $\operatorname{Ran} A_e^T = \operatorname{Ran} A^T$, where $\operatorname{Ran}A^T$ is the range of $A^T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$\newcommand{\Ran}{\operatorname{Ran}}$I am having trouble in understanding the following proof of $\Ran A_e^T = \Ran A^T$, where $A_e^T$ is echelon form of $A^T$, given in my book.

> **Proof :-**
>
> By the definition of echelon form, $A_e = E_{m \times m} A_{m\times n}$, where $E$ is the product of elementary matrices.
>
> $$\Ran(A_e^T) = \Ran(A^T E^T) = A^T(\Ran(E^T)) = A^T(\Bbb R^m) = \Ran(A^T)\tag*{$\Box$}$$

I know that for a linear tansfromation $T$ and a set of vectors $X$, $$T(X) := \{\mathbf y = T(\mathbf x) : \mathbf x \in X \}$$.

We can identity $A^T$ with the linear transformation $A^T : \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$, so by definition $A^T(\Bbb R^m) = \Ran(A^T)$. Hence the last equality.

For the second equality from last, we use the fact that  $E^T$ is invertible and therefore it is onto.

Is my reasoning correct for last and second from last equalities?

How did the author get second equality, $\Ran(A^T E^T) = A^T(\Ran(E^T))$ ? I don't think $\Ran(AB) = A (\Ran(B))$ is true.

Comment: Does $\text{Ran}(A)$ mean rank of $A$?

Comment: @ToanPham No. It means column space of $A$ or range of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\text{Ran }A_e^T=\text{Ran }A^T$ then I believe $A_e^T$ is **not** the echelon form of $A^T$, i.e. $(A^T)_e$ but is rather **the transpose of $A_e$**, i.e. $A_e^T=(A_e)^T$. This explains why we can have $A_e^T=(EA)^T=A^TE^T$.

> Show $\text{Ran}(A^TE^T)=A^T\text{Ran }(E^T)$.

Note that any $i$-th column vector in $A^TE^T$ equals $A^T \cdot \mathbf{c}_i$ where $\mathbf{c_i}$ is the column vector of $E^T$. Every vector in the column space of $A^TE^T$ can be written as a linear combination of column vectors of $A^TE^T$, which then follows that they can be written as $A^T$ times a vector in column space of $E^T$. This results $\text{Ran }(A^TE^T)=A^T \text{Ran }(E^T)$.

Since $E$ is invertible so $\text{Ran } E^T=\mathbf{R}^m$.

> Show $A^T(\mathbf{R}^m)=\text{Ran }(A^T)$.

Similar to previous argument, every vector in column space of $A^T$ can be written as $A^T$ times a vector in $\mathbf{R}^m$.

Comment: So $\Ran AB = A\Ran B$ true in general ? BTW you don't need to use `\text{Ran }` on this page, you can use `\Ran`.

Comment: Also when we write $A^T \Bbb R^m$ what does it mean, we can't just multiply a martix and a vector space.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, $\Ran AB=A \Ran B$ is true in general. And for your second question: This is the first time I saw the notation $\Ran$ so I'm not sure, but according to the above, we don't multiply a matrix to a vector space but rather a matrix to every vector (also matrix) in a vector space so we actually can do that (given certain conditions occur).

Comment: Since $\Ran AB = A\Ran B$ is true then is $\Ran A^T I = A^T \Ran I = A^T \Bbb R^m$ correct proof for $A^T \Bbb  R^m = \Ran A^T$ ?

Comment: Sorry I am still confused about how we can do $A^T \Bbb R^m$, If we consider $\Bbb R^m$ as a matrix of all vectors in $\Bbb R^m$ then it is a infinite matrix.

Comment: Yes, $\Ran A^T=A^T\mathbf{R}^m$ is essentially comes from $\Ran AB =A\Ran B$. I understand the notation $\Ran AB= A\Ran B$ as: every vector in column space of $AB$ can be represented as matrix $A^T$ times a vector in column space of $B$. You can actually prove this is true. It's not about multiplying per se, but rather about representation of every vector in a column space in a specific way.

Comment: The problem of infinity does not matter, since it's a vector space with countable basis. As long as each vector in the basis (or column vectors) of $A^T$ can be represented as $A^T$ times one vector in $\mathbf{R}^m$ then every vector in $A^T$ can be written as such.

Comment: So if you have a basis of $\mathbf{R}^m$, i.e. list of $m$ vectors with one $1$ and the rest is $0$. You times each of such vector with $A^T$ then you will obtain a certain column space of $A^T$. So that means every vector in $\mathbf{R}^m$ times $A^T$ will result in a new vector in $\Ran A^T$. I hope this is clearer. If you still have problem, please tell.